# Do I need to fill previously screw/nail holes in OSB sheathing under vinyl siding?

Tags: exterior, siding

I recently removed an exterior fixture from my home that was attached with screws about 1/8" in diameter. I patched the holes in the house wrap and replaced the siding, but neglected to patch the screw holes in the wood. Should I bother to open it back up and fill the holes or is it fine as it is?

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to patch them unless aesthetical.
If you can not see them no need to patch them.